# How do I replace multiple words from string in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, string, replace

I would like to replace multiple words from below string:

> \njava developer\n

How do I replace \n from start and \n from last from above string?
I used

> replace('\n', '')

but it replace first \n only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace all `\n` without calling replace in a loop you have to use a regular expression. You can use it like this:

```
var test = "\njava developer\n";
var result = test.replace(/\n/g, '');
```

the `g` in the regular expression means replace all occurrences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Vincent!
It works for me.
 I implement like this

str.toLowerCase().toString().replace(/[<b></b>\n]/g,'')

to replace , <\b> and \n all multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks vincent!
It works for me.
I implement like this

```
stringToChange.toLowerCase().toString().replace(/[<b></b>\n]/g,'')
```

to replace

```
 <\b>, <b> and \n
```

all multiple occurrences.